# Driver not working anymore when appending custom node group

Tags: compositing-nodes, drivers

I am creating a custom node group for the Compositor, and I would like to control the size of a cloud texture with a driver within the node group. However, after appending the node group to a new blend-file, the driver is no longer working. I have to manually copy and paste the drivers again for them to work. This is not user-friendly, especially when sharing the node with others. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is a video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/SbEayV4uMLQ

This is a simplified version for demonstration purposes:

[image]

Comment: The Driver is not a part of your NodeGroup. It's a part of your Texture (the size property). So you need to append both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, this doesn't work. Additionally, when I append either the node group or the texture, Blender automatically appends the other.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without doing it manually. If you want to share this, the best thing I can suggest is, creating a frame with the explanation on how to fix the driver inside the node group.